# How do I use byte constants as switch cases in C#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, byte

I'm developing a network protocol that needs to be as low-bandwidth as possible. I've decided therefore that instead of using a header that is a `string` for each message type, such as `"connect"`, `"move"` or `"disconnect"`, it would be better to use a `byte`.

Here's a snippet of what I have so far:

```
// Message types
public static readonly byte CONNECT = 100;
public static readonly byte MOVE = 101;
public static readonly byte DISCONNECT = 102;
```

Now elsewhere I have:

```
switch (in_message.ReadByte())
{
    case CONNECT: Connect(); break;
    case MOVE: Move(); break;
    case DISCONNECT: Disconnect(); break;
}
Client.Recycle(in_message);
```

Visual Studio doesn't seem to like the fact that I'm using byte constants, the specific error message is `A constant value is expected`.

Is there any way I can get these byte constants to work with the switch statement?

Comment: Maybe if you used `100`,`101` and `102` in the switch instead of using a variable.

Comment: It says: A constant value is expected and you are using a readonly, these two are not the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have are read-only fields, which aren't considered constant values (they can be assigned to by a static constructor). Use constants instead:

```
public const byte CONNECT = 100;
```